# Hybrid Inheritence

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to develop a code for hybrid inheritance but this code is not working. Please could you explain me the error and also how can I make this  code better.

```
# creating parent class
class Parent1:
    BloodGroup = 'A'
    Gender = 'Male'
    Genetic_Disease = 'Diabetes'

class Parent2:
    BloodGroup = 'B'
    Gender = 'Female'
    Genetic_Disease = 'Autism' 

    # creating child class
class Child(Parent1,Parent2): # inheriting parent class
    BloodGroup = 'A'
    Gender = 'Female'
    Genetic_Disease = 'Diabetes'
    
    def print_data():
      print(BloodGroup, Gender, Genetic_Disease)
    
# creating object for child class
child1 = Child()
# as child1 inherits it's parent's disease printed data would be it's parent's
child1.print_data()
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense as an inheritance hierarchy. Inheritance doesn't mean "these two classes had a baby"; classes represent a *kind of thing*, and subclasses represent a *more specific* kind of thing than their superclass.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to use classes for what should be instances of one class. And additionally your method `print_data` is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not representing inheritance hierarchy.

But what you want to represent seems following codes using 'self' keywords.

```
class Child(Parent2,Parent1): # inheriting parent class
    BloodGroup = 'A'
    Gender = 'Female'
    Genetic_Disease = 'Diabetes'
    
    def print_data(self):
        print(self.BloodGroup, self.Gender, self.Genetic_Disease)
    
child1 = Child()
child1.print_data()
```

This is a more accurate way to use 'Object', 'Inheritence' concept.

```
class Person:
  hasDNA = True

class Mother(Person): # inherited parent class, Person
  def __init__(self, bloodGroup, genetic_Disease):
    self.bloodGroup = bloodGroup
    self.gender = 'Female'
    self.genetic_Disease = genetic_Disease
 
class Father(Person): # inherited parent class, Person
  def __init__(self, bloodGroup, genetic_Disease):
    self.bloodGroup = bloodGroup
    self.gender = 'Male'
    self.genetic_Disease = genetic_Disease
 
class Child(Person): # inherited parent class, Person
  def __init__(self, bloodGroup, gender, genetic_Disease):
    self.bloodGroup = bloodGroup
    self.gender = gender
    self.genetic_Disease = genetic_Disease
  
  def print_data(self):
    print(self.hasDNA, self.bloodGroup,self.gender, self.genetic_Disease)
    
father1 = Father('A', 'Diabetes')
mother1 = Mother('B', 'Autism')
child1 = Child(father1.bloodGroup, mother1.gender, father1.genetic_Disease)
child1.print_data()
```

Mother, Father, Child Classes are specified classes inherited by Person.

```
child1 = Child(father1.bloodGroup, mother1.gender, father1.genetic_Disease)
```

Above line is not an act of inheriting, just an passing parent's infomation to child.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit of correction:

```
def print_data(self):
    print(self.BloodGroup, self.Gender, self.Genetic_Disease)
```

and print function should work now.